# Creating an n by n grid, where each element is a pointer to an object

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
class ClassName {
    A* grid[][];
}
```

I'm getting that "*declaration of ‘grid’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first*" error. The issue is I won't know the dimensions until I run the program, where the size is one of the arguments.

The instructions state that each element of the grid should be an A* -- i.e., a pointer to an object of type A.

How can I do this?

Comment: How would I go about deleting the grid in the destructor?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you need, and not `std::vector<std::vector<A>>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could opt to define `grid` this way: `A*** grid;`. Of course, you'd have to dynamically allocate memory with this setup:

```
class ClassName {
    A*** grid;
    int nCols, nRows;

public:
    ClassName(int cols, int rows) {
        nCols = cols;
        nRows = rows;

        grid = new A**[nCols];
        for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++) {

            grid[i] = new A*[nRows];
            for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {

                grid[i][j] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }

    ~ClassName() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nCols; i++) {
            delete[] grid[i];
        }

        delete[] grid;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you that make sense! However in the destructor I'm getting "*'grid' was not declared in this scope*"

Comment: Specifically on the "delete[] grid[i]" line

Comment: I actually did do that. I have those two lines in the header file and the constructor & destructor on the cpp file

Comment: That's good! I had forgotten the `public` keyword, so you'd have to add that too if you haven't already; otherwise you won't be able to construct `ClassName` objects outside the class.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you get to `***` in a declaration you are dangerously close to becoming [a Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) and should most often review the design one more time.

Comment: That's true; this would've been better as an academic example rather than a practical one. Using `std::vector`s, as you've mentioned, would be preferable.